# Simple Linux word processor to create trivially styled PDF?

Tags: pdf

I want to create a trivially styled PDF. What's a simple Linux word
processor I can use?:

- I want to embolden some text and put headers on each page w/
  enlarged text. I also want to decide where the page breaks are.
- Is LaTeX good for something like this? Is there a latex2pdf program?
- OpenOffice seems too "big" for this (plus it doesn't work on my machine).
- I consider using HTML and then html2pdf but I'm not sure I could
  do paging like that (unless I broke up each file into multiple HTML
  pages, shudder).
- Would enriched text (or even RTF?) be good for something like 
  this? Are there Linux word processors that can produce these formats 
  and programs that can convert them to PDF?

I sense I'm missing something basic (this can't be hard), but can't 
figure out what.

Comment: LaTeX is perfect for this. PDFs are created  with `pdflatex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LaTeX would do the job. Now the vast majority of LaTeX users produce PDF as their primary format; the command is `pdflatex`. LaTeX would be especially suited if you need an automatable process. In the same lines you could have a look at [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) which is an XSL-FO processor that can output PDF. It may be well suited if your input data is XML.

If you don't need to automate the process, then you may use a simple word processor program such as [Abiword](http://www.abisource.com/) or [KWord](http://www.koffice.org/kword/). Both of them can work in RTF (which should be sufficient for what you need), or in their own file format.